# how best can i split this column in pandas to get a column with genre? [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}

Tags: python-3.x

how best can i split this column in pandas to get a column with the genre? [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'} in this case 'Animation'

Answer (score 0):

use it like this:

```
dict = {'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df['name']
```

and you will get the desired output

Comment: how would you do it with a column of about 3000 rows in a df

Comment: will you please tell me that what is the sole objective or the output that you want